No consigo descargar una imagen desde makito.es
Uso esta función:
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://makito.es/WebRoot/Store/Shops/Makito/6332/BF3A/20D3/013C/1EB5/0A6E/0397/1A3B/2050-000-10.jpg',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));

Pero siempre obtengo un error 403. En postman funciona perfectamente.

en linux : curl https://makito.es/WebRoot/Store/Shops/Makito/6332/BF3A/20D3/013C/1EB5/0A6E/0397/1A3B/2050-000-10.jpg -o img.jpg

Comentas que en Postman funciona sin problema, pero al usar CURL obtienes un error 403.
Quita la última coma donde indica el tipo de petición, pero también agrega información del referer :
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://makito.es/WebRoot/Store/Shops/Makito/6332/BF3A/20D3/013C/1EB5/0A6E/0397/1A3B/2050-000-10.jpg',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer: https://makito.es/',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8'
  )
));


Lo conseguí con estos headers:
            'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:132.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/132.0',
            'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language' => 'es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
            'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
            'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' => '1',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest' => 'document',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode' => 'navigate',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site' => 'none',
            'Sec-Fetch-User' => '?1'

La idea la saque abriendo la imagen con Firefox, inspeccionar => Red, botón derecho encima del archivo de imagen y "Copiar Valor" => "Copiar como cURL (Windows)".
Gracias a todos.
